# Python, list of strings, rows into columns

Tags: python

So, my problem is, i want to transpose my list rows into columns
for example:

["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"] => ["ABC", "ABC", "ABC"]

can't find an efficient way to do it.

Comment: `zip(*(list(i) for i in array))`

Comment: @TomYates: Why convert to `list`? `zip(*array)` is equivalent without needless conversions (though  you need to convert the `zip` `tuple`s back to `str`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a simple use of `zip` and unpacking:

```
strs = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
print zip(*strs)
```

Output will be tuples, though:

> [('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'B', 'C')]

---

For strings you can use:

```
strs = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
print map(''.join, zip(*strs))
# for python 3 use: list(map(''.join, zip(*strs))) # thanks @cesar
```

Output is now a list of strings:

> ['ABC', 'ABC', 'ABC']

`''.join` is used to map tuples to strings.

Comment: If you are using python3 the map function returns a map object, so if you need a list you shuld call list(map(''.join, zip(*strs)))

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
print ([''.join(i) for i in zip(*a)])
```

Answer (score 0):

So this assumes that you are dealing with strings in your example, but you could expand the algorithm for dealing with whatever data type you come across, the logic will remain the same.

```
listRows = ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
transList = []
tempString = ''
for s in range(0,len(listRows)):
    for i in range(0, len(listRows)):
        tempString = tempString + listRows[i][s]
    transList.append(tempString)
    tempString = ''
print(transList)
```

Where transList is the final list you want

Comment: Woah @Reut Sharabani and Abhishek, i did not know about zip and map, those are neat!! if i had enough rep i would Up Vote the two of you haha!!!